# Django 1.4 + Apache WebServer + Mysql and PostgreSQL Connection Error

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have successfully followed the Django 1.4 Tutorial 1-4 (the poll system) and now its running until I deploy it in Apache Webserver 2.2 using Postgres Database. Everytime I access **localhost** I always have "Internal Server Error" but if I use MySQL as my database everything is ok. What do you think is wrong? Did I miss something to configure in Postgre?

Here is my database connection settings in Mysql(Working) and in Postgre(Not Working), both using Apache2.2 + mod_wsgi.so

```
//Postgre
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'django_demo1',                     
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword', 
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',       
    }
}

//MySQL
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'django_demo1',                     
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword', 
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',       
    }
}
```

Other INFO:

OS: windows 7, Python: 2.7, Django: 1.4, Postgre 9.1

Comment: Have you installed psycopg2 module?

Comment: what's the error message in the apache error log file? btw. enable DEBUG=True in your settings.

Comment: Check your webserver's logs if you need to know the details. We can just guess. Could be missing python dependencies for postgresql for example.

Comment: thank you guys. I have found psycopg2 is not found. that solves the problem.

Comment: I already did it! +1 for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to access MySQL but not Postgres, I guess `psycopg2` which is the Postgres adapter for python is not installed. Install psycopg2 using pip.

> pip install psycopg2

Here is the [pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/psycopg2/).

Comment: thanks babu! Yes, i just found out that psycopg2 is missing. After i installed, everything is ok.